# Html onclick как передать элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть вот такой html.
Я хочу вызвать js функцию(конкретнее Jquery).

```js
fun(){
  $(this).css(...);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div onclick="fun()"></div>
  <div onclick="fun()"></div>
  <div onclick="fun()"></div>
</div>
```

Но, это не работает, я помню что надо в `onclick="fun()"` как-то передать сам объект в качестве аргумента, что-то вроде: `onclick="fun(apply)"`

Подскажите точнее пожалуйста, если это вопрос молотка, то просто пожалуйста ответьте как сделать чтобы это работало)

Comment: `onclick="fun(this)"`

Comment: `onclick="fun.call(this)"`

Comment: `<div class="clickable">` и js был бы `$('div.clickable').click(function() {...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function fun(el) {
  el.style.color = "#" + (0x1000000 * (1 + Math.random()) | 0).toString(16).slice(1)
}
```

```html
<div onclick="fun(this)">Первый</div>
<div onclick="fun(this)">Второй</div>
<div onclick="fun(this)">Третий</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Мог бы догадаться)